# mule : How to add map to List?

Tags: mule

I have created a flow Variable which is a list. I have a for-each component , the output of which is LinkedHashMap, now I want to add map to flow Varible list and set it payload. I tried the expression transformer.
`#[flowVars['DataList'].addAll(payload)]`. I am getting the error Error: unable to resolve method: java.util.ArrayList.addAll(java.util.LinkedHashMap) . Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList.addAll accepts a Collection, and adds each element of the collection to the ArrayList. You need to use ArrayList.add instead. The end result of this will be a List of Map objects.

See the Javadoc for java.util.List: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html